# How to pick a nested type of the Generic in typescript to create the new one?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a wrapper function that accepts a generic type. This wrapper returns a function that returns some resulted object and I'm trying to figure out how to produce the type for this object that will contain some custom property where the value will be one of the nested types of the generic. I apologize if the description is a bit vague so here is the code:

```
function wrapper<T>() {
  return function core() {
   /* here I want to 'tell' the compiler the resulted object should 
    * contain all properties from the type T and the *childrenStyles* where the value 
    * should be a *T.style.childrenStyles*
    */
    return {} as T & {
      childrenStyles: Pick<T, "style.childernStyles"> // it doesn't work, unfortunately
    }
  }
}

type ChildrenStyles = {
  Main: {
    [index: string]: string;
  }
};

type Styles = {
  [index: string]: string;
} & {
  childrenStyles: ChildrenStyles;
}

type Props = {
  style: Styles;
}

const resultedCore = wrapper<Props>()();

/**
 * the resultedCore type should be like this
 * {
 *  style: Styles,
 *  childernStyles: ChildrenStyles 
 * }
 * 
 * it's necessary because I want to have the VSCode highlight when I'm doing that
 * console.log(resultedCore.childrenStyles.Main)
 * 
 */
```

I tried to use Pick for this purpose but it doesn't work somehow. 
Also, I prepared the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOmCmqA8AKgHwAUAlIgN4CwAUPYoqjlCKkqJLAohHCwrVGTZq3ZIqAX0ToAzokKIAZMLqjREABYwANgBMWYAMpQAnrpxyAXIgAKMCAGsiAGkQAiOecsA6bXr6eCY+Vh7EiAD0kYgAkohOYHDIiDBQAOQKaAgA5iJMUiKFdMX05riIAMI6BkamFlaIALxqTACy6DBgtrTqogDaXUEAHrbeqF05ALpjUBNgOQDcRfRSywx05TiI9ZYKLb1Mg2Ajs-PTZ5PrMqqHfDWGOCENNlUPdaFy1-RlZhV2qDgmH2rUQ3gatl2Vm+G34YG8YjkIF0UBw+kqAm2LTQWFwBABQLkZHIFHW9EiACoKYwKYgoFptiwkSi0RiWHS-ts5Fo4Mj9IgAEbbXQwJzbekwOQ01q0sGhSGfVzS+6BYJQ17VQIfF6IaXFRC06VpTKIMA4CBWOToVBmQXm9AgOTbeLIdBgKB0uCILToABu4oZiAAasYMUFvTAcloRVGPcgGUhYukALaIfRwSZ0n1QaVwuRwPy6OA5UhM5Go9GY-zvJ7q3wdLrkaU0yL0IA)

Many thanks for any info\help!

Comment: That `Pick(T, "style.childernStyles")` looks quite invalid. Confusing `< >` with `( )`?

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs  thank you for the notice. Don't know how I could miss that, sorry. Fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring/fixing the invalid syntax in `Pick(T, "style.childernStyles")`, here's one way to do it:

```
function wrapper<T extends { style: { childrenStyles: any } }>() {
    return function core() {
        /* here I want to 'tell' the compiler the resulted object should 
         * contain all properties from the type T and the *childrenStyles* where the value 
         * should be a ***T.style.childrenStyles***
         */
        return {} as T & { childrenStyles: T['style']['childrenStyles'] };
    }
}

type ChildrenStyles = {
    Main: {
        [index: string]: string;
    }
};

type Styles = {
    [index: string]: string;
} & {
    childrenStyles: ChildrenStyles;
}

type Props = {
    style: Styles;
}

const resultedCore = wrapper<Props>()();

// Resulting type of resultedCore:
const resultedCore: Props & {
    childrenStyles: ChildrenStyles;
};
```

The `T extends ...` basically tells TS "You need me to pass a type that has `.style.childrenStyles`", then we simply index it to get the style.

Comment: Thank you Kelvin for your suggestion. This solution is pretty elegant and simple. I really appreciated your help because I didn't have any idea it could work in this way

Comment: And one small question: is it possible for the style type in the `Props = {style?: Styles;}` to be optional somehow?

Comment: Yes. Add a `?` in every `style:` (i.e. `style?:`) and one in the `childrenStyles:` in the return statement.

Comment: I've just tried but it doesn't work, here is the demo: **shorturl.at/mzR58**, could you, check it, please?

Comment: Hmm didn't do every change, but it seems like I forgot to turn my strict mode on anyway. Try [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOmCmqA8AKojgB5Q5gAmAzogN6I1QCeANjgPwBcDiEACxhsqqSgGVWHGj0TowLRAF9lAPgAUASgYBYAFCJDiMVBCokoSLAT84YrboNHnJs0nor0dYgDI+g4VEJKRwaXgBRUgg2ECocIgBtAHJmdhwkgF0AGkRwOOAYMBwqVWSAkTEwSTSaTOUAbn1nJX0lIA) instead.